# Why does my div disappear after some AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem I am suffering from for 4 days now. I am making a movie registry webpage. I made a smaller test project to reconstruct the error I get.

**divpingpong.php:** I have 3 divs (A, B and C) and a pencil button outside of them. I include an uploader in div B first inside a *#placeholder* div (when the page loads). I want to use this *#placeholder* multiple times. For example if the user switches to div B, I want to make the uploader visible with javascript. I use the jQuery *.appendTo* function to move the *#placeholder* to the place I wish, then *.show()* it. Div A won't need the uploader. When user clicks on the pencil icon I want to display div C with a content loaded by AJAX and moving the uploader into it. On switching back to div B I want *#placeholder* to move back into div B.

**div_ccontent.php:** This is the file, which is called by AJAX and has the content of div C. It also contains some sort of JS code, which helps (or at least intented to) to move the uploader into the right place.

**The problem:** After a few (more than 1) AJAX calls my entire *#placeholder* div seems to disappear completely. It mustn't disappear, because I want use it to upload pictures at data input (represented by div B) and data manipulation (represented by div C). I know it's not the best method of programming, but I'm not good at writing nice codes. This program is only made for home usage.

**My researches:** I tried every possible solutions and every relevant google search terms (including Stackoverflow), but with no success. I have found a useful link at [technify.me](http://technify.me/user-experience/javascript/executing-javascript-in-an-ajax-response/) about using the *eval()* function to run JS came from AJAX request, but it didn't help me either. I was trying possible soultions and searching for about 7-8 hours all together and it is very annoying.

**Here is my code:**
*divpingpong.php:*

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    include_once("initial.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Div ping-pong</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="easytooltip/js/easyTooltip.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="jsfv.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ajaxfile="div_ccontent.php";

            function switchpage(){
                //$("#div_a").toggle(0);    //if we want to make sure the display is the opposite (show->hide, hide->show)
                var val=$(this).val();
                $("#div_"+val).show();
                if(val=="a")
                    $("#div_b, #div_c").hide();
                else if(val=="b"){
                    $("#div_a, #div_c").hide();
                    var parentid=$("#placeholder").parent().attr("id");
                    var exists=$("#placeholder").length;
                    if(parentid!="div_b"){
                        $("#placeholder").appendTo($("#div_b")).show();
                        //$("#upload_frame").attr("src", "").hide();
                    }
                }
            }

            function domod(){
                $("#div_a").hide();
                $("#div_b").hide();
                $("#div_c").show();
                $.post(ajaxfile, {sid: Math.random}, function(valasz){
                    $("#div_c").html(valasz);
                    $("#div_c").find("script").each(function(i){
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });
                });
            }

            $("#div_b").hide();
            $("#div_c").hide();
            $("#selectpanel").change(switchpage);
            $("img.pencil").live("click",domod);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        img.pencil:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Div ping-pong, that is replace a div with AJAX calls</h3>
    <select id="selectpanel">
        <option value="a">Div A</option>
        <option value="b">Div B</option>
    </select>
    <div id="div_a">
        <b>Div A</b>
        <p>
            This is the place for quick search. There is some amount of text in a table with a few rows, which is in a fieldset.<br />
            This will never contain the certain #placeholder div.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_b">
        <b>Div B</b>
        <p>
            This is the place for data input. There is some amount of text in a table with a few rows, which is in a fieldset.<br />
            Then, comes the uploader in #placeholder:
            <div id="placeholder"><?php include_once("upload.php"); ?></div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_c">
    </div>
    Modify <img class="pencil" src="img/modositas.png" alt="módosítás" />
</body>
</html>
```

*div_ccontent.php:*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $included=strtolower(realpath(__FILE__))!=strtolower(realpath($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]));
    if(!$included && !isset($_POST["sid"])) header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    if(isset($_POST["sid"])) include_once("initial.php");
?>
<b>Div C</b>
<p>
    This is the place for data manipulation. There is a little amount of text in a table with a few rows, which is in a fieldset.<br />
   Then, comes the uploader in #placeholder:
</p>
<p id="additionalinfo">Does the #placeholder exist? (1-yes, 0-no) </p>
<script language="javascript">
    var parentid=$("#placeholder").parent().attr("id");
    var exists=$("#placeholder").length;
    if(parentid!="div_c"){
        $("#placeholder").appendTo($("#div_c")).show();
        //$("#upload_frame").attr("src", "").hide();
    }
    $("#additionalinfo").append(exists);
</script>
```

I can't figure out, what can be the problem. Why does that div disappear? Please answer if you can. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set this `var parentid=$("#placeholder").parent().attr("id");` because you hide `div_b`, and show only if this criteria happens.

Comment: If div_b is selected from the dropdown menu (select), I hide all others (like in the case of A), and if _#placeholder_'s parent is NOT div_b, I move it into that. This is what doesn't work in the case of div C (from the second time, loaded via AJAX).